# AppBar background fills whole screen

Tags: android

My app contains an AppBar which I want to have a background image. So I set the image as to `AppBarLayout:background`, but the image doesn't fit the size of the Bar, but fills the whole screen. I want it to reach only to the end of the TabView, so it doesn't affect the the content below.

My xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:background="@drawable/dunkvert"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">


        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:text="TextView" />

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>


        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
                android:id="@+id/tabItem"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="A" />

            <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
                android:id="@+id/tabItem2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="B" />

        </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Toolbar is the one who actually represents your toolbar, try adding an image view to it inside a frame layout so it can go together with the text view:

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

                <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

               <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:text="TextView" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:src="@drawable/dunkvert" />
            </FrameLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

or simply set the background of the toolbar to the desired image.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:background="@drawable/dunkvert"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">
 <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:text="TextView" />
 </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: The second solution seems good, but the background doesn't lay on the TabView, but above. Can you tell me how to do that as well?

Comment: You want it to reach both the toolbar AND the tablayout? The same background, like in a continuation of the same image?

Comment: Yes exactly, one image and no edge between tabs and toolbar

Comment: With the current layour you can't do that, they have different parent views. In order to make them share a background they'd need to share the same parent and you'd but the backgorund in the parent :/